# Change destination of a location request that's in another view controller

Tags: swift

I am trying to create an app in which, in a view controller, the user will be able to choose the location he wants to find directions and then, after that, a segue will be performed and a MapView will open with the directions he needs to perform. This is the code for the map view and the directions request:

```
    mapkitView.delegate = self
    mapkitView.showsScale = true
    mapkitView.showsPointsOfInterest = true
    mapkitView.showsUserLocation = true

    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled(){

        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

    }

    let sourceCoordinates = locationManager.location?.coordinate
    var destCoordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 36.0922147,longitude: -113.4035741)

    let sourcePlacemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: sourceCoordinates!)
    let destPlacemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: destCoordinates)

    let sourceItem = MKMapItem(placemark: sourcePlacemark)
    let destItem = MKMapItem(placemark: destPlacemark)

    let directionRequest = MKDirectionsRequest()
    directionRequest.source = sourceItem
    directionRequest.destination = destItem
    directionRequest.transportType = .automobile

    let directions = MKDirections(request: directionRequest)
    directions.calculate(completionHandler: {

        response, error in
        guard let response = response else {
            if let error = error {
                print("Something went wrong.")
            }
            return
        }

        let route = response.routes[0]
        self.mapkitView.add(route.polyline, level: .aboveRoads)

        let rekt = route.polyline.boundingMapRect
        self.mapkitView.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegionForMapRect(rekt), animated: true)


    })
```

location manager is defined as `CLLocationManager()`. The destination coordinates are set default as the Grand Canyon National Park, and this code is inside `override func viewDidLoad()`.

In another View Controller, the user will select the place he wants as final destination and then I want to perform a segue into to the map in which the destination will be changed to the one the user wanted, and then the directions will change too. I have tried to do this, but it didn't work:

```
self?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "teste", sender: self)
self?.firstViewController.destCoordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -23.5957034,longitude: -46.675363)
```

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: Performing a segue creates a new view controller, so what does `firstViewController` point to?  (Perhaps you only want to show an existing view controller instead of a segue to a new one.)

Comment: That's right, I just want to show an existing view controller! firstViewController is `var firstViewController: ViewController = ViewController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)`, which is the View Controller in which the MapKit and the default directions are set. Actually, when I perform this segue, the MapView shows up with the default directions, I'm not sure if this `performSegue` is really creating a new ViewController...

Comment: A segue will create a new instance of whatever kind of view controller it connects to in your storyboard.  Has `firstViewController` already been displayed by the time you want to show it with these coordinates?  If it has, you don't want the segue.  If it has not, then you should probably use the segue, set coordinates in prepareForSegue, and get rid of the `firstViewController` variable.

Comment: Yes, `firstViewController` is shown first with the default coordinates (`sourceCoordinates` and `destCoordinates` as set in the code above) . In `firstViewController` the user will find a button that will perform a segue to a new viewController in which there will be several destination options. After he chooses the one he wants to go, then `firstViewController` will open again and change the `destCoordinates` and, therefore, the directions will need to change. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a segue you could just instantiate your next VC with needed params ?

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Storyboard", bundle: nil)
let nextViewcontroller = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "nextViewcontroller") as! NextViewcontroller
nextViewcontroller.destCoordinates = YOUR LOCATION
```

Of course you need to create the param in the next VC like :

```
var destCoordinates : CLLocation?
// or
var destCoordinates : CLLocation!
```

if you decide to create an optional in your next VC you will need to use `if let` if you decide to force unwrap your variable I would recommend to use `precondition(destCoordinates != nil)` in your viewDidLoad to make sure you did set your variable

Comment: can you explain a little more about creating the params in the next VC? kinda new to the language :p